# IE/Edge rendering of SVG elements with Angular attribute directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, svg

Hello out there internet people!  I have one of those many IE specific issues that I'm hoping someone can help me with...

I'm attempting to use ng-transclude inside of an attribute-level directive to transclude content inside of SVG.  I place the attribute on an SVG element and try to render a series of rectangles (or really, whatever SVG element I want) via an ng-repeat.  This all works perfectly with Firefox, Chrome and even Opera.  With IE and the new Edge browser, however, the browser simply empties out the contents that should be transcluded (I get an empty parent element).

```
angular.module("test", []).directive("transcludeTest", [function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    templateNamespace:"svg",
    transclude: true,
    template: '<g ng-transclude></g>'
  }
}]);

<svg>
  <g transclude-test>
    <!-- whatever SVG content I want -->
    <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

results in:

```
<svg>
  <g transclude-test=""></g>
</svg>
```

Even weirder is that using the attribute-level directive on an HTML element (Div etc) works fine.

This is a little difficult to explain, so I've included a Plunker with an example.  It SHOULD render 3 h1 tags with "Testing" and 3 black squares.  In normal browsers, everything loads as expected.  In Microsoft browsers, only the "Testing" text renders.

http://plnkr.co/edit/tx2nKq0NA3GGV6PUwnWq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that IE and Edge just don't support AngularJS with SVG properly.  In order to get it to work, you have to implement a bit of a hack.  Step 1:  remove all transclusions from the Angular SVG Directives.  They just won't work.  Step 2:  set replace:true on all of the SVG directives.

See sample here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/tx2nKq0NA3GGV6PUwnWq

```
angular.module("test", []).directive("angularTest", [function(){
    return{
     restrict: 'A',
        templateNamespace:"svg",
        replace: true,
        template: '<g><rect ng-repeat="step in [1,2,3]" width="50" height="50" x="0" y="10" ng-attr-x="{{step * 50}}" stroke="#dbdbdb" fill="#000000" stroke-width="1"></rect> </g>'
    }
}]);
```

Annoyingly this means that you will have to include everything that WOULD have been transcluded as part of the template.  Alternatively, don't support IE/Edge if you can get away with it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You must wrap the svg content that is getting stripped away with an `<object>` tag, then just the object tag gets removed, leaving the creamy nougat center.

```
angular.module("test", []).directive("transcludeTest", [function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    transclude: true,
    template: "<object type='image/svg+xml' ng-transclude><g></g></object>"
  }
}]);
```

I got some of the inspiration from this article, although his solutions seems like more than is needed. http://blog.akquinet.de/2014/02/26/interactive-svg-with-angularjs-part-2/

Comment: At first glance, your code works correctly.  Upon closer inspection, however, it looks like you are restricting to an Element level directive, so your directive isn't being run and your ng-transclude doesn't occur.  If I switch your restrict to an "A" then the problem rears its ugly head :-/